# How to tun a test suite with different role assignments and profiles

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing

I have a test suite which I must run as various users-profile  I have a teacher, an admin, a teaching assistant, and a student. I must run the test suite using each user. I can create a profile for each user, but how would I call each user? I am using NodeJS and Ava for testing. I figure I could use something like the following, but how do I run the test as each user:

Roles:

```
{ 
    teacher:
          email: ‘teacher@abc.com,
          password: ‘class123’
},
{
     Student:
         email: ‘student@abc.com,
         password: ‘myclsss’
}
```